# How can I add PDF content to a property of an object posted using AJAX and WebAPI

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently, a submit button triggers a javascript function that posts data to a controller action using AJAX.  Form posting is not being used. For example:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                url: "@Url.Action("SubmitRequest")",
                data: {
                    sendDate: sendDate,
                    dueDate: dueDate,
                    startDate: startDate,
                    endDate: endDate, 
                    ...

                },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    popError(request.responseText);
                }
            });
```

I would like to add an additional parameter to this object that holds the binary of a PDF document.  For example:

```
   $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitRequest")",
                    data: {
                        sendDate: sendDate,
                        dueDate: dueDate,
                        startDate: startDate,
                        endDate: endDate, 
                        ...
                        pdf: pdfData                    
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        popError(request.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

All the examples that I've seen showed posting a pdf as the sole value for "data".  Is there a way to include it as part of the data object?

The user will be picking the PDF using a file input element like:

```
    <div class="dcell">
        <input type="file" id="btnUploadStaticPdf" name="btnUploadStaticPdf" value="Attach Pdf" class="btn btn-default" style="display:none" />
    </div>
```

Comment: What data type is pdfData?

Comment: Whatever it needs to be for the object in the controller actions to accept it. I've seen things like var file = document.forms['data']['btnUploadStaticPdf'].files[0]; where btnUploadStaticPdf is the name of the file input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a file to an ajax request you can use a FormData object

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('sendDate', sendDate);
data.append('dueDate', dueDate);
data.append('startDate', startDate);
data.append('endDate', endDate);
data.append('pdf', $('#btnUploadStaticPdf')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitRequest")",
    data: data,
    processData: false,  / So jQuery Doesn't mess with your formdata object
    contentType: false, // So jQuery doesn't set the wrong content type
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        popError(request.responseText);
    }

});
```

On your server pdf will be available via whatever file upload mechanism it supports(`Request.Files` maybe)

Answer (score -1):

You can try converting the PDF to a Base64 encoded string. You could then set the string as a value of one of the attributes in the JSON Object.

```
 var selectedFile = $("#btnUploadStaticPdf").files;
 var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];

 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 var base64 = fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
 ...

 data: {
    sendDate: sendDate,
    dueDate: dueDate,
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate, 
    ...
    pdf: base64 
 }
```

[Encode file to Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)